# Can we pass many objects as parameter of any method with condition statement

Tags: c#-4.0

Can we pass many objects as one argument for method parameter with conditional statement
for example

Two class : one and two

Passing method is

```
public void passe(one||two)
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Why cant you overload the method instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have conditional arguments on a method the way you described.

If the two arguments are of the same type (or belong to an inheritance chain), you can simply pass in the value conditionally to the method.

Alternatively, you can use [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

```
public void passe(typex one = someXdefualt, typey two = someYdefualt)
{
}
```